# Indexing of table is messed up which causes the queries to take extremely long to fetch the rows

Tags: sql, database, indexing, schema

I have a table A `[Schema: key_id, x,y,z,...]` with a key id column which is unique and has increment seeding of 1. Now I have a table B `[schema: key_id, key_idOfA, x,y,z,....]` which is a back up for A with a similar schema (only diff table B has its own `key_id` and it also maintains original `key_id` of Table A).

I have a service which transfers some rows from A to B based on a where clause. I tried this service once and it worked fine by transferring rows from A to B. Now to check this service again I had to transfer the rows (key_idOfA, x, y,z,...) from B back to A.

TO avoid loosing the original key_id of Table A here I first used

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT A ON
```

and transferred the rows which worked fine. After transfer I used

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT A OFF
```

Now when I run the service again it takes a lot of time to get few rows from table A which causes a timeout. Precisely speaking it takes 5 mins to get 30,000 rows on SQL Server Management Studio. From the service, the query times out due to a 3 mins timeout.

I am aware switching a table's identity insert ON and OFF is a bad practice but this was a test bed DB and I would never do it on Production DB.

My questions:

1. Is the indexing messed up due to which the query is taking so much of time? Or is there some other issue?
2. Could I have taken a different approach to transfer the rows back without messing up indexing?

Answer (score 0):

Well, What you can do to look into WHY it is slow, look at the Actual Query Plan.
In SSMS this is done throught the Query menu in the top, the select Actual Query plan (Or CTRL-M)
When you run the query afterwards you get an extra tab beside your Results and Messages tab. it is called Execution Plan.
When you look into that, you have to start on the far right. That is where the query starts. Look for high percentages. If you see index scans or table scans, those are worse then a index seek, which is a faster method.

If you see that you have high percentages with table/index scans, try to defrag your indexes.

You might wanna take a look at a script i wrote to defrag indexes : [www.plixa.nl/fragment-an-index](http://www.plixa.nl/fragment-an-index/)

Hope it helps, if not, let us know :)